# Kotlin coroutine suspendCancellableCoroutine on Google ApiFuture callbacks hanging

Tags: kotlin, callback, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

New to Kotlin and trying to understand coroutines and flows a bit better in a not completely trivial usage I have hit a circumstance that is beyond my understanding though it may be a bug or more likely something have got fundamentally wrong.

In trying to port [a google bigquery java](https://github.com/googleapis/java-bigquerystorage/tree/main/tutorials) example to Kotlin I came up with (slightly edited for brevity)

```
package io.mehitabel.bqstreamwriter

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.*
import com.google.api.core.ApiFuture
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutureCallback
import com.google.api.core.ApiFutures
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.*
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.*
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWriteClient
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors

import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow

import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject

import java.io.*
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException

object JsonWriterDefaultStream {

    val batchCount = AtomicInteger()
    suspend fun run(
        projectId: String,
        datasetName: String,
        tableName: String,
        dataFile: String
    ) {

        val bigQueryService: BigQuery = BigQueryOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService()

        val writer = createDefaultStream(bigQueryService, projectId, datasetName, tableName)
        batchWrite(writer, dataFile).collect {
            println(it.rowErrorsCount)
        }
        // works only if inline callback code used
        println("${batchCount.get()} Batches written")

    }

    suspend fun batchWrite(jsw: JsonStreamWriter, sourcePath: String): Flow<AppendRowsResponse> =
        jsonStreamWriter(jsw).flatMapConcat { jsWriter ->
            getFileDataBatchedJson(sourcePath)
                .map{chunk ->
                     coroutineScope {
                         val future: ApiFuture<AppendRowsResponse> = jsWriter.append(JSONArray(chunk))
// <suspendCancellableCoroutine>                         
//                         future.await()
// </suspendCancellableCoroutine>                         
// <InlineCallback>
                         ApiFutures.addCallback(future, object : ApiFutureCallback<AppendRowsResponse> {
                             override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
                                 throw t
                             }
                             override fun onSuccess(result: AppendRowsResponse) {
                                 batchCount.incrementAndGet()
                                 result
                             }
                        }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
                        future.get()
                    }
// </InlineCallback>
                }
        }

    fun jsonStreamWriter(jsWriter: JsonStreamWriter): Flow<JsonStreamWriter> = flow {
        jsWriter.use { emit(it)}
    }


    fun InputStream.linesToFlow(): Flow<String> =
        flow {
            bufferedReader()
                .useLines { lines ->
                    lines.forEach { line -> emit(line) }
                }
        }

    fun getFileDataBatchedJson(dataFile: String): Flow<List<JSONObject>> {
        val reader: InputStream = FileInputStream(File(dataFile))
        return reader
            .linesToFlow()
            .map { it -> JSONObject(it) }
            .chunked(100)
            .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
    }


    fun createDefaultStream(
        service: BigQuery,
        projectId: String,
        datasetName: String,
        tableName: String
    ): JsonStreamWriter {
        // Get the schema of the destination table and convert to the equivalent BigQueryStorage type.
        val table: Table = service.getTable(datasetName, tableName)
        val schema: Schema? = table.getDefinition<StandardTableDefinition>().getSchema()
        val tableSchema: TableSchema = BqToBqStorageSchemaConverter.convertTableSchema(schema!!) // force npe if null
        val parentTable: TableName = TableName.of(projectId, datasetName, tableName)
        val client = BigQueryWriteClient.create()
        return JsonStreamWriter.newBuilder(parentTable.toString(), tableSchema, client).build()
    }

}

private object BqToBqStorageSchemaConverter {
// omitted for brevity
}

/**
 * Original usage in https://github.com/JetBrains/teamcity-google-agent/blob/master/google-cloud-server/src/main/kotlin/jetbrains/buildServer/clouds/google/connector/ApiFuture.kt
 */
suspend fun <T> ApiFuture<T>.await(): T {
    try {
        if (isDone) return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            get()
        } as T
    } catch (e: ExecutionException) {
        throw e.cause ?: e // unwrap original cause from ExecutionException
    }

    return suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont: CancellableContinuation<T> ->
        val callback = ContinuationCallback(cont)
        ApiFutures.addCallback(this, callback, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())
        cont.invokeOnCancellation {
            cancel(false)
            callback.cont = null // clear the reference to continuation from the future's callback
        }
    }
}

private class ContinuationCallback<T>(
    @Volatile @JvmField var cont: Continuation<T>?
) : ApiFutureCallback<T> {
    override fun onSuccess(result: T?) {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        cont?.resume(result as T)
    }
    override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) { cont?.resumeWithException(t) }
}
```

When this runs with the `< InlineCallback >` marked code it completes and exits but when the
`< suspendCancellableCoroutine >` code is used it completes again but then hangs without exiting so I am looking for any help or clue to find out why and how perhaps to fix it.

Subsequently I added in `arrow.fx.coroutines` and converted the map to a `parMapUnordered`.

When I set the concurrency to > 1 the `< suspendCancellableCoroutine >` `await()` version now exits but if concurrency is set to 1 it reverts to hanging after having written all the batches.

Comment: I'm having problems to understand what's the observed behavior. What does it mean that "When this runs with the code" and "when the code is used"?

Comment: Apologies the post stripped out the pseudotags that are in the code block comments. It hangs when the future.await() which comes from the  < suspendCancellableCallback > section is used and runs to completion with the < InlineCallBack > code is  used as shown. The final part about parMapUnordered applies when the await() code is used working when concurrency > 1 and hanging when it = 1